# R: Printing random forest model to html

Tags: html, r, knitr, random-forest, r-markdown

I'm working on a Rmd document that I would like to compile to html using knitr package via the HTML export mechanism available in RStudio. The problem can be reproduced with the code below:

***Example***

```
# Set up
rm(list = ls())
data(airquality)
attach(airquality)
packs <- c("randomForest", "knitr", "xtable", "xtable", "stargazer")
lapply(packs, require, character.only=T, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# Model
airquality <- na.roughfix(airquality)
dummy <- randomForest(Ozone ~., data = airquality)

# Problem
kable(dummy)
xtable(dummy)
stargazer(dummy)
```

The issue is further illustrated by the output below:

***Output***

```
> # Problem
> kable(dummy)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class "c("randomForest.formula", "randomForest")" to a data.frame
> xtable(dummy)
Error in UseMethod("xtable") : 
  no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "c('randomForest.formula', 'randomForest')"
> stargazer(dummy)

% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

Is it possible to force the `randomForest` output into a nice html table that would be presentable in a markdown document?

Comment: You need to look at `str(dummy)` and decide what parts of that list object are needed. The dataframe class is designed for holding data in equi-length columns, not for arbitrary structured objects. Sometimes what you really want will be assembled someplace in the `summary(dummy)`-object.

Comment: Shouldn't be that hard to add this feature to [pander](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander), please submit a ticket (or pull a request) and I will be happy to look into it.

Comment: @daroczig thanks for the kind suggestion, naturally, I will submit the ticket.